# According to the HTML5 spec, what is the most clear way of presenting a list with headings?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility, semantics, semantic-markup

I'm having trouble finding the correct way of presenting the following product properties according to this version of the HTML5 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/

[image: List of properties]

There's the `<dl>` element for description lists. There's the `<table>` element for multi-dimensional data. There's the `<ul>` element for unordered lists. None of these alternatives seem right to me.

To prevent bloat I'll just show two rows of properties in my examples:

### Definition list

```
<dl>
  <dt>Lampholder</dt>
  <dd>E27</dd>
  
  <dt>Watt</dt>
  <dd>5W</dd>
</dl>
```

A `<dl>` doesn't seem right because it doesn't reflect the row-like presentation of the attributes, neither does it have multiple definitions.

### Table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lampholder</td>
    <td>E27</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Watt</td>
    <td>5W</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A `<table>` doesn't seem right since it's not multi-dimensional data. It's just a list of properties with headings.

### Unordered list

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <h5>Lampholder</h5>
    <span>E27</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h5>Watt</h5>
    <span>5W</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

A `<ul>` doesn't seem right since `h*` elements should represent headings of sections which these list items clearly aren't. The markup also doesn't really specify that the `<span>` are values connected to the preceding heading.

Could someone shed some light on this?

---

**On hold:** I *absolutely don't* agree that this is opinion based. There is a spec for a reason. It's **not** correct to use `<h2>` elements for paragraphs of text just because you feel like it, so why would this be a question without an objectively correct answer?

Comment: It's subjective, but I'd go with a table since, with column headings, you could easily add other products to the same table. I am, though, voting to close because it's opinion-based, and other than the strength of the presented argument, there's no objective way to pick a single 'correct' or 'best' answer.

Comment: you should try few examples on semantic-ui, which are quite semantic.... http://semantic-ui.com/elements/divider.html

Comment: I don't agree that it's opinion-based, @David Thomas. While there are several ways of *presenting* the attributes the way I want to, the HTML specification is very clear in *how* certain elements should be used. I'd love to get some insight from someone who's well-versed in the spec, since they probably have considered this use-case already.

Comment: The question isn’t even well-defined. “Semantic” is a very vague word in this context.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. You could do a heading of the lightbulb name, an image of the bulb, then a `dl` of the attributes. However, when you read up how assistive technology deals with DL's, you'd probably look for another display mechanism, most people usually chose a `table` as David said.